# Copper Water Pipes used as Electrical Ground

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a section of copper water pipe that burst behind tiled shower wall. Since the pipe run is along an exterior wall subject to winter temperatures, I'm considering replacing this section with PEX given it is less prone to freezing. But in this house (built 1959) copper water pipes are used as electrical grounds in multiple above ground locations, i.e., where 2prong receptacles were replaced w/3prong receptacles w/the addition of a copper wire (green/insulated)-1 end wound under green ground screw on receptacle, other end bound by a grounding clamp to a nearby cold water pipe. Splicing in PEX will interrupt the "continuous ground". Is PEX therefore  contraindicated or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to consult a licensed electrician in your area, but you can probably simply bond a 12 or 14 gauge bare copper wire to the copper pipe on either side of the section you replace with PEX to maintain the preexisting continuous ground.

Pay more attention to the first part of this answer than the second part.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the sizing of the jumper is based on the size of the service conductors. I also think the smallest size jumper is 8 AWG.

Comment: You may be correct, and now that I think about it, the wire connecting more recent grounding bars in breaker boxes to the actual grounding rods is usually 6 AWG. I mentioned 12 and 14 because I was thinking of the ground wire in normal 15A/20A romex.

Comment: Code has changed since this question was asked but the clarification in the 2017 code allows the pipes to be used within 5' of the entrance of the building unless a facility under supervision.

Answer (score 2):

Caution is also indicated when the copper pipe is "interrupted" because copper pitting can then occur, depending on water quality, as a result of DC current. For example, the installation of a water filter or water softener without "bridging" across the installed equipment will result in copper pipe problems.....

Answer (score -5):

It is unlikely that anything electrical is connected to the pipes above the ground level. Normally the ground connection is from the junction box in the basement to the main where it enters the house.

Nevertheless, for safety reasons all the pipes needs to be grounded so you will have to attach grounding jumping wires to keep all the plumbing grounded.

If you have any question about it, you can check your outlets using a tester to make sure they are grounded after you do the repair. The tester looks like this:

[image: outlet tester]

There are also ground testers you can use on the pipes to make sure they are all grounded.

Comment: -1 It is common practice *(and in my locality, **required**)* to ground copper pipes.  This increases safety *(if a hot wire touches a pipe, you want a breaker to blow, not every pipe in the house to become charged)*. Also, since the pipes have a separate path to the earth outside, it helps prevent stray current-loops.  An outlet tester cannot tell you if your pipes are grounded, unless OP's pipes were the *only* path to ground.

Comment: I think that he would still want a continuos ground for the copper pipes so if someone drops a hairdryer into a sink, the copper piping becomes a path to ground and not the person that tries to retrieve it from the water. An outlet tester gives some indication that there's a path to ground perhaps through some incidental path, but it won't tell you have you have a *good* ground that will protect you in an electrical fault.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Apparently this is true, I have updated my answer.

Comment: The ground wire leading to an outlet is normally bonded to neutral in the main panel. Your outlet tester is effectively testing for continuity between neutral and ground and therefore cannot tell if the system is actually grounded! Some people cheat installing 3-prong outlets without an available ground by add a jumper between the neutral and ground terminals of the outlet. Your tester also cannot detect this. This answer is worthless and should be deleted.

Comment: By your description here, I now recognize one incidence in my house of a jumper between neutral and ground which long puzzled me. The receptacle was added during a kitchen remodel by former owner to service a refrigerator in new location. It's probably a stretch to assume this false ground contributed to a blown evaporator fan motor in my fridge which took a power surge after a major blackout And I now have a false sense of security provided by the Surge Protector in place on same receptacle